# Сайт не обновляется в браузере

Tags: вёрстка, кэширование

Прошу помощи!Делал сайт в Studio Visual Code, всё проверял в брузере, через расширение openserver. Всё работало, дошёл до определённого этапа, как будто вёрстка зависла, меняю, что-то всё по прежнему в браузере видно.Я даже удалил файл со стилями.Всё равно блок который удалил отображается. Подскажите как можно исправить? Предполагаю произошло некое кэширование с которым я никогда до этого не сталкивался или что-то ещё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо большое, проблема заключалась в том,что Sass не успевал обрабатывать и добавлять в CSS, видимо мой компьютер не тянет 10 SASS файлов с итоговыми CSS 500 строчек кода))))
Удалил файл SASS создал новый, потихоньку из старого файла скопировал код,нашёл баги в коде и всё заработало.
А насчёт раскэширования, спасибо за комбинацию буду применять, когда снова заподозрю неладное.

Comment: Такие детали необходимо добавлять в текст вопроса, чтобы читающим не приходилось бы гадать, что у вас там SASS.

Comment: Что бы решить вопрос я много перепробовал, вопрос мой был исходя из гипотез на тот момент решения!

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите на странице ctrl+F5 или ctrl+shift+R для обновления со сбросом кэша.